# Issue with Wordpress and 960 Grid System

Tags: css, wordpress, thumbnails, 960.gs

I've been trying to implement the 960 grid system on a Wordpress theme that I'm currently developing. I've got a index page with project thumbnails which are set to take up 4 out of 12 columns each, making it 3 columns of thumbnails.

But for some unexplainable reason, the third column won't appear – it's being pushed down into a total of two columns.

I've made a basic test page in a text editor in which there's no issue, but as soon as I apply it to Wordpress it will only display two columns.

This is the wordpress page at which the problem occurs:
http://dev.niklaslundberg.com

And below is the test that I've created in a text editor, which acts the way I'd like it to in wordpress:

```
<html>
    <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/reset.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/text.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/960.css" />


    <style type="text/css">

    .image {

    }

    .image img {
        max-width: 100%;
        height: auto;
    }

    #content {

    }

    </style>

    </head>

    <body>

    <div id="content" class="container_12">


    <div class="grid_4 image">
        <img src="1.jpg">
    </div>

    <div class="grid_4 image">
        <img src="2.jpg">
    </div>

    <div class="grid_4  image">
        <img src="3.jpg">
    </div>

    <div class="grid_4 image">
        <img src="4.jpg">
    </div>

    <div class="grid_4 image">
        <img src="5.jpg">
    </div>

    <div class="grid_4 image">
        <img src="6.jpg">
    </div>

    <div class="grid_4 image">
        <img src="7.jpg">
    </div>


    </div>



    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because of the horizontal margin on your 4 column divs. The 12 column container has width = 940px, and each 4 column div has width 300px, with 10px left & right margin. So, 3x320px = 960px, which is greater than 940px container width. If you make container 960px and get rid of the container 10px left & right margin, it works. You have to remember that horizontal margins don't collapse, so if you have 2 divs side-by-side with 10px left/right margin, you get 20px margin between the 2.

Comment: Apparently it's because the loop is a child grid to the 12 column wrapper parent. And so, the first item for each row must the class alpha, and the last on each row would have the class omega. The child grid is what has has added the extra padding. Still haven't figured out how to apply alpha to the first div of every row, and omega to the last (in my case third) div of every row. Since it's a loop it gets complicated for e beginner. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Then the loop that creates the child grid needs a counter that increments each time through the loop. And before it echoes a child grid, you test the counter for divisibility by three, something like `if ($counter%3 == 0) $class="alpha"; else if ($counter%3 == 2) $class="omega";`